# Limit involving $\sqrt[n]{n!}$

Tags: analysis, limits

> a)Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}$.
>
> b)Let $a_n=\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$. Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n-1}{\ln a_n}$.

So, I've managed to find the first two limits, which are $\dfrac1e$ and $1$, but don't know what to do with the last one.

Mathematica says it's 1, but I have no idea how to get that. Could I get a **hint** on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that your last limit can be written as $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{b_n} - 1}{b_n}$$ where $b_n = \ln a_n \to 0$. Now interpret the limit as a derivative.

Comment: Ah, thanks very much! What about $\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}-\sqrt[n]{n}$?

Comment: For that one, first make sure you know $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n}$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}$.

Comment: @ryagami use [Stolz-Cesaro Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) to conclude $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}}{1} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (\sqrt[k+1]{(k+1)!}-\sqrt[k]{k!})}{n}$

Comment: @r9m: That is very slick, +1.

Comment: Wow, very elegant. Thank you so much! :)